# Check calendars from a Google calendar API service account

Tags: google-calendar-api

I created 3 new users in my g-suite account and I am using a service account to access calendars and events, but these 3 new users cannot see their calendars if I can create events for them forgive me my English I am not a native speaker
NOTE: new users I already added in the calendar part the permissions of that service account

Comment: Hello @GermanGarcia, how were the events created? Which settings did you apply to them? Cheers!

Comment: The events are created from the service account and they are created well what happens is when I retrieve the calendars of all the users I am doing it in the following way: IList<CalendarListEntry> calendars = service.CalendarList.List().Execute().Items; this retrieves all the user's calendars except the 3 new ones that I have created

Comment: Hello @GermanGarcia, changes may take some time to propagate. Are you still encountering the issue? Moreover, are you able to retrieve the calendar by using this link [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list)? Cheers!